# JQuery: How to select all child elements after nth child and place in new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big list of `<li>`s. I want to select all `<li>`s after the 20th instance and wrap them in an element.

I'm just not sure how to collect all the `<li>`s after 20.

I've tried `:gt(20)` and `.slice(20)` with no luck.

Would anyone know how I could achieve this?

So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-long-menu').each(function( index ) {
        var itemLength = $(this).find('li').length;

        if(itemLength >= 20){
            var extraItems = $(this).find('li:gt(20)').html();
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='col-md-2'>" + extraItems + "</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MeltingDog   Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-long-menu').each(function() {
        var itemLength = $(this).find('li').length;
        for(i=20;i<itemLength;i++)
        {
            var extraItems = $(this).find('li').eq(i);
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='col-md-2'>" + extraItems + "</div>");
        }
    });
});
```